# struggling to avoid repeated values from the list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have a list1 like this:

```
['A' '0' '0' '0' 'A']
```

I have a dict1 like this:

```
{1.12: 0, 1.21: 'A', 1.22: 'B', 1.41: 0, 1.31: 'A', 1.32: 'B', 2.11: 0}
```

I am looking forward to get the dict1 keys based on the dict1 values in the list1 using the following

```
np.array([dict1[x] for x in list1])
```

Outputing :

```
[1.31 3.41 3.41 3.41 1.31]
```

However I would like to output:

```
[1.21  1.12  1.41  2.11 1.31]
```

How could I get to this output without repeating the dictionaries keys as a result of the list comprehension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your list comprehension:

```
[dict1[x] for x in list1]
```

What you are trying to do is, iterate over the list and gather all the values associated with the items in list as a key in dictionary. Your code has following porblems:

a. What if key not found in dictionary, it would lead to an exception.
b. You need to check if value is present in dict with data same as what is in list.

Solution would be something like:

```
np.array([key for key, value in dict1.items() if value in list1])
```

This way, you iterate over the dict and you check for existence of the value in list as the same time and only if its present then take it else ignore the same.

A much more efficient way to do look up would be to convert the `list1` to set, so your in clause can return you result in O(1) time rather than O(N) to get better performance. Should be like:

```
myset = set(list1) ##assuming this you could create beforehand if possible instead of list
np.array([key for key, value in dict1.items() if value in myset])
```

Comment: Also, the value in the list is of type string & key in the dictionary is of type integer.
Hence...  
`np.array([key for key, value in dict1.items() if str(value) in myset])`

Answer (score 0):

I think the structure of your data is making this problem more difficult than it is. If you change this the problem becomes much easier to solve.

First, you are trying to find keys by values when dicts are meant to be used the other way around.

Second, you are trying to find multiple items by one value. Which can be done by popping items from a list of values.

So if you restructure your data like this:

```
data = {'A': [1.31, 1.21], 'B': [1.32, 1.22,], '0': [2.11, 1.41, 1.12]}
```

You can just lookup the appropriate list and pop off the value like this:

```
results = [dict2[value].pop() for value in list1]
```

Note: on a side note, your list is missing the comma's in your question.